# IOS/Objective-C: Get value of property of object in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to grab a relationship property of an object from a mutable array.

```
theNewItems[0].step is giving the error,  Property 'step' found on object of type id.
```

Here is how I created the array:

```
 NSMutableArray* theNewItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

 [theNewItems addObject:_itemsOnLoad[0]];
 [theNewItems addObject:_itemsOnLoad[1]];
 [theNewItems addObject:_itemsOnLoad[2]];
```

And here is how the array logs out

```
<Items: 0x1706842e0> (entity: Items; id: 0xd000000001900004 <x-coredata://AFF50577-0975-4124-AC70-074F355B73A0/Steps/p100> ; data: {
    item = "0xd000000016000000 <x-coredata://AFF50577-0975-4124-AC70-074F355B73A0/Dare/p1408>";
    sid = 545;
    step = "step three";
    wasdeleted = nil;
    whenadded = nil;
}),
    <Items: 0x170684330> (entity: Items; id: 0xd000000001840004 <x-coredata://AFF50577-0975-4124-AC70-074F355B73A0/Steps/p97> ; data: {
    item = "0xd000000016000000 <x-coredata://AFF50577-0975-4124-AC70-074F355B73A0/Dare/p1408>";
    sid = 544;
    step = "step two";
    wasdeleted = nil;
    whenadded = nil;
}),
    <Items: 0x170684380> (entity: Items; id: 0xd000000001780004 <x-coredata://AFF50577-0975-4124-AC70-074F355B73A0/Steps/p94> ; data: {
    item = "0xd000000016000000 <x-coredata://AFF50577-0975-4124-AC70-074F355B73A0/Dare/p1408>";
    sid = 543;
    step = "step one";
    wasdeleted = nil;
    whenadded = nil;
})
)}
```

Should I be creating the mutablearray differently?  Or how can I grab the property "step"?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there only one entity you are dealing with or many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarification...

An `NSArray` (mutable or not) can hold objects of *any* type. So, when you "get" an object from the array, the compiler needs to know *what* you are getting.

Example:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:40];
[a addObject:[UIView new]];     // add a UIView
[a addObject:@"A string"];      // add a NSString
[a addObject:@100];             // add a NSNumber
```

You now have an array with a View, a String and a Number. If you try to do this:

```
UIView *v = a[0];
NSString *s = a[1];
NSNumber *n = a[2];
```

You'll get warnings because while the types are correct, the compiler doesn't know that.

To actually *use* the objects you've stored in the array, you have to cast them. So, with the same example data:

```
UIView *v = (USView *)a[0];
NSString *s = (NSString *)a[1];
NSNumber *n = (NSNumber *)a[2];
```

is fine... you can use your `v` `s` and `n` objects as you'd expect.

For your specific object type of `Items`, you could:

```
Items *thisItem = (Items *)theNewItems[0];
NSString *theStep =  thisItem.step;
```

or, more concisely:

```
NSString *theStep = ((Items *)theNewItems[0]).step;
```

In 2015, Apple introduced "Lightweight Generics" into Objective-C. This allows you to declare an array of type:

```
NSMutableArray <Items *> *theNewItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

[theNewItems addObject:_itemsOnLoad[0]];
[theNewItems addObject:_itemsOnLoad[1]];
[theNewItems addObject:_itemsOnLoad[2]];

NSString *theStep = theNewItems[0].step;
```

And no more casting. Note that you still add your Items objects to the array in the same manner.

Another note: Reading around you'll find some debate about `arrayWithCapacity`. The most reliable info I've found explains that it perhaps *used to* make memory management a bit more efficient, but these days it's simply a "hint" and, really, only makes for readability as in:

> "When I review my code, I see that I'm expecting this array to hold 40 objects."

It does not, however, *pre-allocate* memory... nor does it ***limit*** the array to 40 elements - the array will still expand as you continue to add objects to it.

Comment: Wow.  This is one of the clearest, answers on SO I have ever read.  Wish I could give it more than one upvote. I went with the generic lightweight version and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `arrayWithCapacity` you can just make an array using `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` which will have no limit on capacity.

To get the property just say `((Items *)theNewItems[x]).step`, `x` being the index at which you want the property. Also if you want to skip the casting step when pulling the object out of the array define your `array` as `NSMutableArray<Items *> * theNewItems = [[NSMutablearray alloc] init]` then you can just say `theNewItems[x].step`

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `arrayWithCapacity` - real benefit is readability, and the OP may have some other reason for using it. In any case, it had nothing to do with the issue. You *could* edit your answer to make it much more clear *why* the need to cast it.